# Cant get first character in array of strings

Tags: c

I want to get first char character of each string. Here a example:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    int size = 2;
    char** text = (char**) malloc(sizeof(char*) * size);
    for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        char buf[80];
        fgets(buf, 80, stdin);
        text[i] = (char*)malloc(strlen(buf));
        strcpy(text[i], buf);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(text[i]); ++i) {
        printf("%c ", text[i][0]);
    }

}
```

In last for loop, program falls in Segmentation fault. I dont know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `strlen` function returns the number of characters in the given string **not including** the terminal `nul` character; however, the `strcpy` function copies all characters **including** that terminating `nul`!

So, your allocation for `text[i]` is not quite big enough and, by writing beyond the buffer's bounds, you are getting undefined behaviour.

Add an extra character to the `malloc` call:

```c
    for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        char buf[80];
        fgets(buf, 80, stdin);
        text[i] = malloc(strlen(buf) + 1); // Need space for the terminal nul!
        strcpy(text[i], buf);
    }
```

Or, more simply, use the [`strdup`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/experimental/dynamic/strdup) function, which achieves the same result as your `malloc` and `strcpy` in one fell swoop:

```c
    for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        char buf[80];
        fgets(buf, 80, stdin);
        text[i] = strdup(buf);
    }
```

Either way, don't forget to call `free` on all the buffers you allocate.

EDIT: You are also using the wrong 'limit' in your final output loop; this:

```c
    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(text[i]); ++i) { // strlen() is not the # strings
        printf("%c ", text[i][0]);
    }
```

Should be:

```c
    for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i) { // "size" is your number of strings!
        printf("%c ", text[i][0]);
    }
```

Comment: i add +1 at malloc and doesn't work, same as strdup. And yes, i know about free i just drop it out of snippet. https://onlinegdb.com/Sy12R54cL

Comment: But you still have `for(int i = 0; i < strlen(text[i]); ++i) {` in your second loop. See the "EDIT" part of my answer, and change that to `for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {`.

Comment: @Georgii, minor issue, casting malloc is unnecessary in C.

Comment: @anastaciu Good call! I'm normally quite pedantic about that, but somehow missed it today.